# Web Services and Computer Services to access low level system functions

Tags: web-services, asp.net-mvc, service

So I think I'm in the right place to ask this question. Its fairly conceptual.

I love web development, I work in ASP.NET MVC 3/4/5 C# and have created industry standard applications such as CRM's and Test Case Documenting.

I'm very aware of the limited capabilities of Web Application over Desktop Applications. Desktop applications can obviously invoke system level operations, such as reading barcode scanners (leftfield I know).

I feel, that this can be possible with web applications through the use of HTML 5 WebSockets and Web Services.

Is it possible to abstract out all the domain level architecture from a ASP.NET MVC application into a Web Service and have the Web Service handling, effecitively, the database.

So is it possible through the use of a Desktop Service, connect to that Web Service to take advantage of the Desktop Service's ability to invoke system level operations?

Now, initially, the Desktop Service will be run on the Web Server, and this is exactly what I want for now.

In the long run, this technology would only be running in an Intranet environment. I'm really not interested in the Internet Scope, and none of what has been said is in reference to the Internet Scope.

Comment: Have a look at SPA applications.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application